# WinJS - XHR - Is it impossible to set the referer?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, xmlhttprequest, winjs

I'm working on a WinJS app for a company that uses Referer is their API.

Unfortunately I can't find a way to do this, not even for Cookies!

---

Here is a code example:

```
Q.when(WinJS.xhr({
  url: "http://localhost:8888/api/auth/",
  type: "GET",
  headers: {
    "If-Modified-Since": "Mon, 27 Mar 1972 00:00:00 GMT",
    "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/api/"
  }
}));
```

---

WinRT seems to use the same behavior IE and other browsers do. Where Referer and Cookie headers are removed from the request.

Any workarounds?

Comment: Other headers may be forbidden too: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Referer for authentication you should consider switching to a proper authentication system. Something like API keys.

Referer was never designed to be a tool for authentication, so it does a really bad job at it.

Comment: It's a `legacy` system and it uses referers, not as authentication, but as part of the whole. Not everyone has the luxury of working on perfectly engineered systems.

Comment: This is a serious limitation though. Is there a way to work around it? ie. can you disabled the Referer check or would that open up the webservice too much?

Comment: The software wasn't built in house and the company is stuck with it. I have no idea why Referer is being used... and can't disable it.

Comment: Well, there is no way to spoof it with AJAX as you've found. Can you make it so the referer is actually correct? If it's a matter of going up one dir you might be able to get a workaround that way.

Comment: If AJAX actually sends the previous URL as a Referer header then I believe I'm saved! :)

Comment: Can you add a custom header, like: `X-Referer`? (this requires changes in the legacy code obviously).

Answer (score 0):

What about using AtomPubClient as a workaround?

Try this:

```
function doRequest3() {
    var reader;
    var client = Windows.Web.AtomPub.AtomPubClient();
    var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://example.com");
    client.setRequestHeader("Referer", "http://localhost:8888/api/");
    client.retrieveMediaResourceAsync(uri).then(function(stream)
    {
        reader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(stream);
        return reader.loadAsync(999999);
    }).done(function (bytesRead) {
        var contentString = reader.readString(bytesRead);
        document.getElementById("content").innerText += "Content: " + contentString;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```